# JSON-LD example uses 'name' property for 'Person', but the property is not in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am a newbie to JSON-LD. I saw the following example JSON-LD from http://json-ld.org/playground/

```
    {
       "@context": "http://schema.org/",
       "@type": "Person",
       "name": "Jane Doe",
       "jobTitle": "Professor",
       "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
       "url": "http://www.janedoe.com"
    }
```

When I look at the [`Person` schema](http://schema.org/Person), the property `name` is not there. There is `givenName` and `familyName`.

How is this a valid structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Person` type is a subtype of `Thing`. More specific types inherit properties of the parent type.

See the Schema.org [`Person` type page](http://schema.org/Person). You'll see a list of recognized properties for `Person` type but further down on the page you'll also see a list of recognized properties for `Thing` type. The recognized `Thing` type properties can be marked up for `Person` type. The `name` property is listed in `Thing` type.

Comment: Good to see you here @Grace

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more fields. Examples:

```
"jobTitle": "SEO Freelance Consultant",
"knows":"John Doe",
"children": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "your child's name",
    "disambiguatingDescription": "Provide a description that fits their professional job."
}
```

After months of testing on multiple sites, we find this format works well.